# PHP home made query function doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am just starting to learn PHP and believe that to learn I have to practice, make mistakes and correct them. I honestly do not know PHP thus my question must seem simple and maybe ilogical to some of you. Please excuse me if I bother with it, but I want to learn.
Thank you.
My problem is that I want to make a function that can be called from a different PHP file whenever I need to query MySQL. function queryMysql(), it is called from within function createTable(), when I cal createTable().

```
function createTable($name, $query)
 {
queryMysql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $name($query)");
echo "Table '$name' created or already exists.<br />";
 }

function queryMysql($query)
{
$result = $conection->query($query) or die(mysqli_error());
return $result;
}
```

I call createTable() from a different PHP file like this:

```
createTable('members',
    'user VARCHAR(16),
    pass VARCHAR(16),
    INDEX(user(6))');
```

I include the files with include_once where the functions are from where I call the functions but when I load the file the browser does not display anything at all, not even errors.

Can somebody help me learn why it seems to not execute my functions? Thank you.

Comment: You're referencing an undefined variable `$connection`. You need to pass it as a parameter to the function or use `global $connection` to access the global variable.

Comment: Hi yes sorry I forgot to clear up that. I used $conection as the variable in 

$conection = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

I do not know if I was to declare it as global. Did I?

Comment: I honestly don;t see great value in exposing a createTable type of functionality unless you app for some reason absolutely needs to be creating tables on the fly, and even then the act of passing in table anem and field/index definitions separately seems odd. Why would you simply not use mysqli or PDO in an object oriented fashion instead of trying to do what you are trying to do?

Comment: I gess the value comes when I use the function queryMysql() evry time I want to perform a query. I just call the function from wherever I want/need the query.

Answer (score 0):

First you should check why you don't get any errors displayed. Usually that is because in your servers php.ini file display_errors is set to false.

The easiest way to check that is to create a file phpinfo.php with a single line that calls

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

The two values to check for are [display_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) (if errors are to be displayed at all) and error_reporting (what kind of errors are displayed)

You can set both with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

In your script the $conection variable is not available in the queryMysql() function. If you are using a global variable (which is considered bad habit) you have to say so at the beginning of the function by using "global $conection;". The keyword to look for is "variable scope".

A better way is to have $connection as a parameter in the queryMysql() function (like $query).

Comment: Thank you. Yes it does report errors because I have tested the connection, I thought that maybe it wasn't connecting in the first place so I tried to connect to the database and issued a direct query, not from the function, and it worked perfectly it created the tables and columns. and I modified it to give errors and it does display errors like it should. I will try add the parameter $connection because I do not want to make it global. I will try that and if it does not work will come back here. Thank you for the help.